# Is OTG support on a phone is a Hardware dependent feature

Tags: hardware, usb-on-the-go

I will be buying a Xolo Q800 -X-Edition Phone that has a MediaTEK MT6589 chipset.
Searching on all forum sites, i found that this phone does not support OTG.

So i want to ask that does OTG availability depends upon the hardware or the chipset on the phone ?

Or it can be enabled in any phone via rooting and some under the hood tweaking.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, USB OTG requires capable hardware, software on which it's enabled and the right drivers.

For example, the Nexus-Series of Google don't allow USB OTG from software-side.
However, if you're rooted (and the hardware would support it) it's an easy way to enable it.

[Chainfire](http://www.chainfire.eu/) made an application which enables/disables USB OTG.

**This only works, if your hardware *would*  support USB**

You can find it on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount&hl=de)

Comment: Chainfire also made [a handy tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics) to test whether your device supports USB OTG, as well as a [database of reports on the use of the tool](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/) so you can check before you buy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, USB on-the-go requires special hardware on the host device, as well as the appropriate kernel drivers and drivers for all the USB peripheral profiles you need to connect.

Answer (score 0):

USB OTG is actually both - hardware and software dependent.

For example, the hardware may have the OTG specification, but the phone software restricts the use of OTG.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, USB OTG is actually both - hardware and software(OS) dependent.

For example the motorola moto defy came with froyo 2.2 and eclair 2.1. And hence no support for OTG. But after rooting and loading ported Kitkat 4.4 ROM it supports OTG without any hiccups.