# Why is my phone ignoring OTG USB?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, usb-on-the-go, file-management

I have 2 phones.
 1. Android 4.4.4 - When OTG USB is connected, it automatically mounts with no problems and I can manage files, watch movies from it, etc.
 2. Android 6.0 - when OTG USB is connected, phone fully ignores it (does nothing).

Why can't second phone mount it exactly like a first does? Do I have to install some application that takes care of it? First phone is rooted, second is not. Can that be a problem?

Comment: What phone is it?

Comment: 1st - Lenovo Vibe Z2 -----  
2nd - Huawei P8 Lite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not the android version describes that it can connect OTG(On-The-Go), its the capability of the device. Huawei P8 Lite has no OTG connectivity as described here : [P8 lite review](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Huawei-P8-lite-Smartphone-Review.146655.0.html)

Comment: Thanks! Last question -  it is stated that port itself doesn't support OTG. So i suppose there is no software that can do it. Or is it?

Comment: USB OTG requires capable hardware, software on which it’s enabled and the right drivers. Source : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68329/is-otg-support-on-a-phone-is-a-hardware-dependent-feature