# LG Premier (LGL62VLv) not OTG Compatible. Hack it to making it compatible?

Tags: rooting

Hi I bought an LG phone strictly for one purpose, I need to use it as a video screen for VR goggles. I intend to hook up a camera to it and use it as my eyes in a cosplay [youtube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ladGoi2EDcs&t=2s) My problem I have encountered is

Comment: Where's your problem?? How could you leave an incomplete question??

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170215/why-is-my-phone-ignoring-otg-usb/170224#170224

Answer (score 0):

I searched on Google but nothing says it supports OTG.

There are 2 possibilities:

1. The phone has a hardware voltage regulator that can uprange the 3.7V from battery to 5V, then there surely is a way to modify the system to allow OTG.
2. The phone does not have a voltage upranger... Give up and have a good sleep :)